# Perl code to rename bulk files

Tags: perl

I have some files in a dir, now I want to rename the files(add suffix and change extension also).

Input:

```
XXIN123.timestamp.dat
XXIN123.timestamp.dat
XXIN123.timestamp.dat
XXIN123.timestamp.dat
XXIN123.timestamp.dat
```

Final output:

```
XXX.123_456.newtimestamp.XXIN123.timestamp.csv
XXX.123_456.newtimestamp.XXIN123.timestamp.csv
XXX.123_456.newtimestamp.XXIN123.timestamp.csv
XXX.123_456.newtimestamp.XXIN123.timestamp.csv
```

First search for particular pattern files in a dir, then add suffix to them.

```
$oldpat = "XXIN123"
$newpat = "XXX.123_456"
```

Then rename all the `.dat` files to `.csv`

It's not working in first run but run properly in 2nd run and overrite 1st file.

CODE:

```
use File::Copy;
use POSIX;
use strict;

my ( $dir, $oldpat, $newpat, $destdir );
my ( $oldname, $currenttime );
$dir         = '/home/sd1/a1';
$destdir     = '/home/sd1/a1/destination';
$oldpat      = "XXIN123";
$newpat      = "XXX.123_456";
$currenttime = strftime( "%Y%m%d%H%M%S", localtime );
opendir( DH, $dir ) || die "Cannot open $dir: $!";
my @files = readdir DH; 

foreach (@files) {
    $oldname = $_; 
    ## Original find and replace
    s/$oldpat/$newpat.$currenttime.$oldpat/;
    next if ( !-f "$dir/$oldname" );
    if ( !rename "$dir/$oldname", "$destdir/$_" ) { 
        warn "Could not rename $oldname\n";    #$oldname to $_: $!"
    } else {
        print "File $oldname renamed to $_\n";
    }   
    close(DH);

    # renaming
    opendir( DIR, $destdir ) or die "Can't opendir $destdir: $!";
    while ( defined( my $file = readdir DIR ) ) { 

        # ignore current and parent directory . and ..
        next if $file =~ /^\.\.?$/;
        my $new = $file;

        # substitute new file extension
        $new =~ s/\.dat$/\.csv/;
        rename( $file, $new );
        print "File $file renamed to $new\n";
    }   
    close(DIR);
}
```

Comment: Your first file begins with `XXIN123` and the rest begin with `XIN123`.  Is that actually how they are named?

Comment: I don't see you copying any files, even though you have `use File::Copy;`.  Are these files already in the destination dir?

Comment: The second loop is called inside the foreach loop. Hence each time around the outer loop it tries to rename all `.dat` to `.csv`.

DH is closed inside the foreach loop, ie it is closed for each element in `@files`. That should probably be moved to before the loop.

It is worth adding `use warnings;` near the top of the file. 

Saying "*It's not working in first run but run properly in 2nd run and overrite 1st file*" mean, saying "it's not working" does not tell us what it is doing or not doing. I suggest fixing the obvious problems and then explaining what problems remain.

Comment: looking at the sample data, I wonder which Operating System you are using which allows multiple file names with the same name in the same location...

Answer (score 1):

There is a Perl-based `rename` command around — it was in the 1st Edition of the Camel Book, but has been referenced in older SO questions and is available on the internet.  (You might find it named as [`prename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/prename.1.html).)

You can use that to do the job:

```
rename "s/(.*)\.dat$/XXX.123_456.$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S').\$1.csv/" *.dat
```

The first part splits the file name into the section before the `.dat` suffix and the suffix; the replacement part uses the current date/time calculated by the `date` command and formatted using a variant of the ISO 8601 date/time format.  It adds the fixed prefix, the new date/time, the old prefix, and the new suffix – and is applied to all the `.dat` files in the current directory.

#### POC

```
(
mkdir junk
cd junk
for file in $(seq -f 'XXIN123.2014010118000%.0f.dat' 0 9); do cp /dev/null $file; done
ls -1
rename "s/(.*)\.dat$/XXX.123_456.$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S').\$1.csv/" *.dat
ls -1
)
```

#### Output

```
XXIN123.20140101180000.dat
XXIN123.20140101180001.dat
XXIN123.20140101180002.dat
XXIN123.20140101180003.dat
XXIN123.20140101180004.dat
XXIN123.20140101180005.dat
XXIN123.20140101180006.dat
XXIN123.20140101180007.dat
XXIN123.20140101180008.dat
XXIN123.20140101180009.dat
XXX.123_456.20140101181530.XXIN123.20140101180000.csv
XXX.123_456.20140101181530.XXIN123.20140101180001.csv
XXX.123_456.20140101181530.XXIN123.20140101180002.csv
XXX.123_456.20140101181530.XXIN123.20140101180003.csv
XXX.123_456.20140101181530.XXIN123.20140101180004.csv
XXX.123_456.20140101181530.XXIN123.20140101180005.csv
XXX.123_456.20140101181530.XXIN123.20140101180006.csv
XXX.123_456.20140101181530.XXIN123.20140101180007.csv
XXX.123_456.20140101181530.XXIN123.20140101180008.csv
XXX.123_456.20140101181530.XXIN123.20140101180009.csv
```

If you want my version of the `rename` command, send email (it's what I used, of course, but it is closely based on the original code).

If you decide you must use Perl to create the new timestamp, you have to work harder (and it's very non-Perlish to reinvent the wheel).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;
use File::Copy;
use POSIX;

my $dir         = '/home/sd1/a1';
my $destdir     = '/home/sd1/a1/destination';
my $newpat      = 'XXX.123_456';
my $oldpat      = 'MHINOCC13';
my $currenttime = strftime( "%Y%m%d%H%M%S", localtime );

for my $currFile (<$dir/*.dat>) {
    my $fileName = basename($currFile);
    next unless $fileName =~ /^$oldpat-\d+-\d+[.]dat$/;

    $fileName =~ s/dat$/csv/;
    my $destFile = "$destdir/$newpat-$currenttime-$fileName";

    print "Copying: $currFile ->  $destFile\n";

    if ( copy( $currFile, $destFile ) ) {
        print "Success!\n\n";
    }
    else {
        warn "Copy failed: $!\n\n";
    }
}
```

This uses a [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) (`<>`) to read the source dir.  In the `for` loop, [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) extracts the filename and that's checked with a regex to filter only those files you want.  Next, the filename is changed to the format you want, then [File::Copy](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.18.1/lib/File/Copy.pm) is used to copy the source file to its new filename in the destination dir.

Be aware that the `copy` routine will overwrite any existing files of the same name in the destination dir, so use this script at your own risk.

Comment: *with a regex* : YAY \o/

Comment: @grebneke -OK, that just made me fall off my chair! :)

Comment: I ran the above code, but no luck, even the script didnt enter in for loop

Comment: @user3115515 - Then there are no dat files in `/home/sd1/a1` which match the file-name pattern you gave.  Place a `print $fileName, "\n";` right below `my $fileName = basename($currFile);`, to see the filenames.

Comment: I am able to get list of files:

Comment: MHINOCC13-828771-20131030104100.dat
MHINOCC13-828772-20131030104009.dat
MHINOCC13-828773-20131030104101.dat
MHINOCC13-828774-20131030104102.dat
MHINOCC13-828775-20131030104103.dat
MHINOCC13-828776-20131030104105.dat
MHINOCC13-828777-20131030104104.dat
MHINOCC13-828778-20131030104106.dat
MHINOCC13-828779-20131030104107.dat
MHINOCC13-828780-20131030104108.dat
MHINOCC13-828781-20131030104109.dat
MHINOCC13-828782-20131030104110.dat

Comment: @user3115515 - Your actual filenames were different from the examples you gave, so the script didn't work.  It now updated: `$oldpat` reflects the current pattern;  the filtering regex was updated for dashes (you showed only periods); `$destFile` was updated to include dashes--like in the old filenames.

Comment: with samll modification in loop condition                                           for my $currFile (<$dir/actual-patter-to search*>) {                          the code works :))  Thanks a lot for your valuable time.